# Run VB.net exe without the need for install

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a simple program that was working fine as a stand alone exe.  There was no need to install the program and you could put the single exe file on multiple computers and it would run fine.

I made one small change and now it doesn't work.  I moved the database connection procedures to a separate module (connection.vb).

The program works fine when I run it in Debug mode from the solution.  But when I try to run it from the exe in the debug folder, it throws an error about a mis-formed connection string.  So I'm assuming that it can't find my new module file (connection.vb).

I tried setting 'Copy to output directory' to always and 'Build Action' to compile.  That didn't fix it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you accessing connect.vb as a file? Or is it part of the project with public objects you access? If the latter there should be no need to move the file so it can be "found."

Comment: It ended up being a different issue than what I originally assumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to debug it to understand what happens. For instance you could add a messagebox that shows you the connectionstring so you can see how it is different from direct debugging. Or add a try/catch around the failing part so you get the exception-reason.

Comment: ok this worked.  I just assumed that it couldn't locate the added module.  But when I added some messageboxes it was communicating with the module.  There seems to be a difference when accessing the my.settings between debug and exe.  Issue resolved!

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit more complicated than its worth, but could you move your database procedures to a custom namespace, add a reference and use an imports directive to the relevant classes in your application?